# Why StringBuffer#append throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, stringbuffer

I have the code which tries to append 2 SttringBuffers:

```
logBuf.append(errStrBuf);
```

In logs I see following trace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 90
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.getChars(AbstractStringBuilder.java:325)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.getChars(StringBuffer.java:201)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:404)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:253)
```

I cannot understand the cause of the issue.

Can you provide example with constants?

Can it be related with concurrency?

Can you propose solution?

Comment: JavaDoc says `append(StringBuffer)` synchronizes on destination SB (logBuf in your case) but not on source SB. So concurrency may indeed be a problem if errStrBuf is changed while the method is running.

Comment: You could go with StringBuilder if you don't intend to use it with multiple threads modifying it, as StringBuilder is not synchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can have to do with concurrency. As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append(java.lang.StringBuffer)):

> This method synchronizes on this (the destination) object but does not
>   synchronize on the source (sb).

So, if `errStrBuf` is changed in the process, it may yield this error. Synchronize on it yourself, as such:

```
synchronize (errStrBuf) {
   logBuf.append(errStrBuf);
}
```

using the same synchronized-block wherever the `errStrBuf` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Some poking around the Java sources shows `StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer sb)` delegates to `AbstractStringBuilder.append(StringBuffer sb)` which does this:

```
    // Length of additional sb.
    int len = sb.length();
    // Make sure there's room.
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    // Copy them through.
    sb.getChars(0, len, value, count);
```

`StringBuffer.getChars` delegates to `AbstractStringBuilder` again so `getChars` looks a bit like:

```
public void getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char[] dst, int dstBegin)
{
    if (srcBegin < 0)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcBegin);
    if ((srcEnd < 0) || (srcEnd > count))
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd);
    if (srcBegin > srcEnd)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("srcBegin > srcEnd");
    System.arraycopy(value, srcBegin, dst, dstBegin, srcEnd - srcBegin);
}
```

Note that you are getting *String index out of range: 90* so it must be the `srcEnd > count` returning true. So the string that is being appended is now shorter than the `len` that was passed. Clearly it must have been fiddled with by another thtread.